# Error using tikz externalize with TeXnicCenter

Tags: tikz-pgf, texniccenter

When I compile my document i get the following error

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/myfile-figure1" \def\tikzexternalrealjob{myfile}\input{myfile}"' did NOT
 result in a usable output file 'tikz/myfile-figure1' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'writ
e 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/OReilly_Gerard_Th
esis-figure1.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

I am using TexnicCenter to compile the document and have the following in the path to the compiler:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe -shell-escape
```

and this in the:

```
-synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"
```

The PDF file is still produced no problem but I know this error should not be occurring.

My LaTeX skills are ok at best so hopefully I am making a glaring mistake here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved the problem. I had two versions of MiKTeX installed on the same machine.

Crisis averted.